# Perceptron - AND operator

Tags: python, perceptron

I used this code to implement AND operator, but line that separates regions is not properly calculated. It is going through points [1, 0] and [0, 1]. What to do in order to correctly separate regions?

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

data = [[0,0],[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]]
labels_and = [0, 0, 0, 1]

x = [points[0] for points in data]
y = [points[1] for points in data]

plt.scatter(x, y, c = labels_and)
plt.show()

classifier = Perceptron()
classifier.fit(data, labels_and)

print(classifier.score(data, labels_and))

result = classifier.decision_function([[0, 0], [1, 1], [0.5, 0.5]])
print(result)

x_values = y_values = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
point_grid = list(product(x_values, y_values))
distances = classifier.decision_function(point_grid)
abs_distance = [abs(x) for x in distances]

distance_matrix = np.reshape(abs_distance, (100, 100))

heatmap = plt.pcolormesh(x_values, y_values, distance_matrix)
plt.colorbar(heatmap)
plt.show()
```

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gObdn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision boundary is correct because everything `>` is classified as class 1, and everything `<=` as class 0. 
However your way of visualizing the absolute value of the out come of the classifier prediction is maybe misleading?

---

The sklearn docs refer to the English wiki article which uses the following definition for a perceptron:

[image]

Since the only class 1 label is the point `(1,1)`, the upper right hand corner we can choose i.e. `w = [2,2]` and `b=-2` to correctly classify `(1,1) as 1` and `(0,0), (0,1), (1,0) as 0`.

The points (1,0) and (0,1) will lie on the decision boundary since `2*0+2*1-2 =0`. However we also could have chosen `b=-3` and our classification problem would still be solved correctly. The difference is that the points (1,0) and (0,1) no longer lie directly at the boundary since `2*0+2*1-3 <0`.

Lets see what parameters our trained perceptron learned! To access them you can see from the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html)

```
w = classifier.coef_[0]  
b = classifier.intercept_
```

If you print them you probably obtain `w=[2,2]` and `b=-2`. To derive the line representing the according decision boundary you can consider the edge cases where `w0*x + w1*y + b == 0` and solve for x. You will obtain:

[image]

So plotting this will lead to something like this:

```
m = -weight[0]/weight[1]   
n = -b/weight[1]    
plt.plot(x_values, m*x_values+n)
```

[image]

which is the dark blue valley you are seeing in your picture. Also our points (1,0) and (0,1) lie on the boundary. You can play around with `b=-3` where you obtain a line with a higher y-intercept which you are probably expecting?

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, your answer helped me to better understand. You are right I was expecting to obtain higher y-intercept line because I saw it in some examples. My intercept was `b = - 2` and when I changed `random_state` to some value that is not zero by default I got different results for intercept and weights.

Answer (score 0):

Decision boundary was calculated correctly, but I expected it to be different. This is thoroughly explained in @v.tralala answer to this question. What I found out in meantime is that if `random_state` is given value other than zero (for example `random_state = 100`), different values of intercept and weights will be calculated, thus decision boundary will be closer to point (1,1).[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hJUW.png)